# Python application menu

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I'm writing an application menu in Python for a linux Desktop Environment I'm creating, and I'm wondering if there is a module that will allow me to read .desktop files, and create a Dict/Object from the results.

If there isn't, I would like some tips on how to go about writing this myself.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thank you! That looks excellent! Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it please.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I left a comment because I didn't have time to flesh it out yesterday but I will do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you are referring to (.desktop files) are structured similarly to .ini files for many applications, as seen in [this example on the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#File_example):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application                          # Indicates the type as listed above
Version=1.0                               # The version of the desktop entry specification to which this file complies
Name=jMemorize                            # The name of the application
Comment=Flash card based learning tool    # A comment which can/will be used as a tooltip
Exec=jmemorize                            # The executable of the application.
Icon=jmemorize                            # The name of the icon that will be used to display this entry
Terminal=false                            # Describes whether this application needs to be run in a terminal or not
Categories=Education;Languages;Java;      # Describes the categories in which this entry should be shown
```

Sections are headed by `[Bracketed Text]`, and everything else is key-value pairs separated by `=` (I have also seen `:`).

Python has the built-in [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module to handle these. That link is the technical documentation but the PythonWiki has [a page with simpler examples](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples). This library does precisely what you asked for: it reads files formatted like .desktop files into objects and dicts.

The first example on the wiki shows this clearly:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> Config
<ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x00BA9B20>
>>> Config.read("c:\\tomorrow.ini")
['c:\\tomorrow.ini']
>>> Config.sections()
['Others', 'SectionThree', 'SectionOne', 'SectionTwo']
```

We import `ConfigParser` (renamed to `configparser` in Python3), instantiate it, and tell it to read the file. `Config.sections()` is now a list containing all the section headers `[Bracketed Text]`.

There are various flavors of ConfigParser objects depending on your needs. The basic one has methods like `getint`, `getboolean`, etc., which take a section and an option and try to return it coerced into the specified Python object. There are also methods like `items` and `defaults` to return the items and defaults respectively from a section given as an argument.

I don't know enough personally about .desktop files to know what sorts of things you might encounter or how exactly you need to configure the parser, but this should get you started.

Comment: Unrelatedly, someone really needs to update that PythonWiki page. Hardly any of the code complies with PEP8!

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in open() function with parameters set to read. If you have trouble using the function consider having a look at the python reference [Python Library Reference, open() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). There you'll find a comprehensive explanation of how to use the function and it's parameters. Youtube and Google will also give you enough tuts on how to read and write to files in python.

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: I can read and write files fine. I was looking for help on parsing Linux .desktop files.

Comment: That's fine, I'm glad I was able to clarify.